# modal-backdrop Bootstrap v3.3.7 on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue with chrome and Botstrap v3.3.7 modal-backdrop.

Here is what is happening[image: backdrop-modal]

The Problem: 
When there is scrollable content in the opened modal, Initially the backdrop is positioned as is should (whole screen) but after i scroll the modal-backdrop stays at top.

I have not changed any original classes for bootstrap. And I have checked the height of the modal is as it should be(whole screen) but still there is this rendering glitch or something else?

This issue is happening only on latest chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you build a basic fiddle in order to identify the issue?

Comment: Sure will try to, and I also noticed same issue appears on Opera(latest)

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue in the fiddle...